# Count cells containing Chr(160) character in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I use the following code to remove all Chr(160) characters, i.e. the non-breaking spaces which occur occasionally after pasting manually (depending on the source of copying).

This works fine so far:

```
Worksheets(2).Range("A:A").Replace Chr(160), "", xlPart
```

How can I count the number of cells containing this character before removing it? I tried the following code for this but unfortunately that's not working:

```
varBlankCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Chr(160) & "*")
```

Comment: Your last parenthesis is too early! `varBlankCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("A:A"), "*" & Chr(160) & "*")`

Comment: @R3uK: Thanks. That was just a typo here, not the issue in the code. Corrected it now. :)

Comment: Ok, So do you have any results or want is happening? Because the line looks fine, except that you don't specify the sheet you want to count on!

Comment: @R3uK: Wow, actually that was the issue. Thanks so much and sorry for this beginner mistake. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! ;) I've added an answer so that you can close the subject! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always specify the sheet you want to work with :

```
varBlankCount = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"), "*" & Chr(160) & "*")
```